# Device error: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to mobile apps. i installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 for the first time. However when i tried to run the code with android emulator i have this issue:

Device error: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Can you tell me what I can do with the error. i have successfully installed intel X86 emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)?

[image]

[image: Intel VIrtualization Technology]

Comment: You need to enable HAXM in your BIOS. There's a hardware setting that controls it there. Please note that not all PCs support HAXM, although most new ones will.

Comment: I have enable Intel virtualization technology in BIOS. but still, it doesn't works.